# React select + Hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

Tengo el siguiente select, este se encuentra en un modal para crear o actualizar clientes, lo que quiero es seleccionar una opcion por defecto, la opcion por defecto carga bien cuando uso la propiedad value de react-select sin embargo al momento de querer cambiar de opcion esta no cambia, pero si uso defaultValue no me selecciona una opcion por defecto, pero si me deja cambiar de opciones

```
              <Controller
                  name="pIdTipoCliente"
                  control={control}
                  rules={{ required: true }}
                  defaultValue={tipoCliente}
                  render={() => (
                    <Select
                      placeholder='Tipo de cliente'
                      menuPosition={'fixed'}
                      options={tiposCliente.data?.tiposDeCliente?.map((_tipoCliente: ITipoCliente) => ({
                        label: _tipoCliente.NombreTipoCliente,
                        value: _tipoCliente.TipoCliente
                      }))}

                      onChange={(selectedOption: SingleValue<{ label: string; value: string }>) => {
                        setValue('pIdTipoCliente', selectedOption?.value);
                      }}

                      value={{
                        label: tiposCliente.data?.tiposDeCliente?.find((_tipoCliente: ITipoCliente) => _tipoCliente.TipoCliente === tipoCliente)?.NombreTipoCliente || 'Tipo de cliente',
                        value: tipoCliente || 'Tipo de cliente',
                      }}
                    />)}
                />
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad, ya verificaste en la documentación de react-select  el comportamiento de value y defaultValue y como se deben configurar? Saludos